# Google custom site search (business edition) how to make search results showed in a pop up window

Tags: javascript, popup, google-search-api

I have a question about the google custom site search on my site.

I have paid 100$ to get custom site search on my site everything works only one thing i can't fix.

I have set google site search to display the results on a new page, this worked perfect!

The problem is i will get it in a popup window not in a new window on the same page!
I have tried to add a popup script but every time i change the extention search.htm it will no longer do antyhing so i can't give it an onclick event or anything!! :(

This is the javascript for the search bar:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('011481879946604973384:9cjokptmuey');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.enableSearchboxOnly("search.htm");
    customSearchControl.draw('cse-search-form', options);
  }, true);
</script>
```

and this line:   `options.enableSearchboxOnly("search.htm");`   will make it go to search.htm where the search results displayed

Hope some one can help me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) to show `search.htm`.

Comment: it won't work or i cant fix it :(   -   (tanx for realy fast replay)

Comment: You just stop the browser from navigating to search.htm and load the search.htm with given search keywords in an iframe.

Comment: it is already a iframe but on a new page my intention is to make te new page a pop up page so people stay on the same page!